# Proof that the gamma function has a minimum between $x=1$ and $x=2$?

Tags: gamma-function

So I know that the gamma function $\Gamma(x)$ for $x>0$ has a minimum at $x_{min}$ which lies between 1 and 2. Where does this follow from though? I know that the gamma function is defined as below:
$$\int_0^{\infty} {exp(-t) t^{x-1} dt}$$

Comment: You at least know it has an _extremum_ on $[1, 2]$ from just evaluating $\Gamma(1) = \Gamma(2) = 1$.

Comment: And then if you evaluate it numerically at, say, $1.5$, you find a value less than $1$.

Comment: Robert Israel proposed to calculate $\Gamma(1.5)$ numerically. Refraining from numerics  we could employ the doubling formula of Legendre $\Gamma(\frac{x}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1+x}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{x-1}}\Gamma(x)$ at $x=2$ giving $\Gamma(\frac{3}{2}) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ which is $\lt 1$ since $\pi \lt 4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ΟΚ, we have that $\Gamma''(x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}{(\log t)}^2t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt>0,\ \forall x>0$. By the comment of Arthur above, Rolle's theorem implies that there is an extremum in $(1,2)$ and the positivity of the second derivative guarantees that this is a minimum.

The only thing that you have to do, is to verify the passage of the second derivative inside the integral. This is a technical detail, that I leave up to you. However, if you know measure theory, there is a standard theorem to use for this. Otherwise you can take $\Gamma(s)$ as a function of a complex variable on $\Re(s)>0$ and pass the derivatives in the integral. In Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of Functions* you can find theorems for passing derivatives with respect to a complex variable into integrals with respect to a real variable.